# Setting filter for on-device logging in Android

Tags: android, logging, logcat

When you log something in Android, it puts a line in a fixed-size buffer. If you get more messages than fit in the buffer, old messages are discarded. You always see a fixed-size window of the most recent log messages.

Running logcat will give you the current contents of this buffer, and if left running, it will show you new events that are logged. You can filter the output of logcat so that, for instance, you see only messages belonging to a certain tag.

> Is there any convenient facility whereby only events with a certain tag are placed into the fixed-size buffer in the first place?

I'd like to be able, basically, to tell Android that I only want the Log class to record events with my tag. I don't want it to record all events and process them later, since my events are rare, and other events are so common that they will cause my events to be evicted from the buffer.

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve leaving the device plugged-in (i.e., leaving logcat running and redirecting filtered output to a file). A viable solution would be to write my own on-device logging system (writing to a file that I create), but if I can get this for free from Android logging, I'd prefer that.

I've looked around and haven't had a lot of success so far.

Comment: I think you will have to create your own logging system if what you are aiming for is to disable -every- message except your own.

Comment: @Jave Maybe it's possible to have the logging system define a new circular buffer, like the events or radio buffer, to use for my tag? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any convenient facility whereby only events with a certain tag are placed into the fixed-size buffer in the first place?

On a rooted device, perhaps, though I am not aware of one.

On a non-rooted device, you have no right to affect other apps' logging, or the OS' own logging.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What about this: can the logging mechanism automatically put events with my tag into its own circular buffer? I understand that there are different buffers on the device, but I don't know if these are static or if more can be defined.

Comment: @Patrick87: "What about this: can the logging mechanism automatically put events with my tag into its own circular buffer?" -- no, though you can use `DropBoxManager` for that sort of ring buffer. I don't know how easy it is to view what gets logged there, though.